# Can you install Macports to the home directory and still have everything work?

Tags: macos, macports

I do not have root access on my computer, and I would like to install Macports. That raises a problem, however, because installing Macports requires sudo. This [link](http://www.jduck.net/blog/2008/12/12/install-macports-in-local-home-directory/) shows how you can install Macports to the home directory, but will everything work properly?

e.g. all packages work right, no conflict between files, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: @miken32 Sorry for not looking at this again. I haven't been on SE for several months. It did work, but Macports would always throw errors, something about no Xcode found, but I had the command line tools so everything still worked. Also, because I had Homebrew installed in my home directory, it complained about finding a Macports install, but nothing ever failed to build.

Answer (score 5):

Yes! Installing MacPorts [like that](https://www.jduck.net/blog/2008/12/12/install-macports-in-local-home-directory/) without root privileges still works perfectly after more than 10 years.

Just to echo the article here: compile from source ([instructions](https://www.macports.org/install.php#source)) to build it for your username in a directory you choose e.g. `~/macports/`:

```
./configure --prefix=${HOME}/macports --with-install-user=${USER} --with-install-group=staff
```

Then use `port` the way you normally would, but without `sudo`.

PS: I guess MacPorts will regain some popularity since HomeBrew [dropped formula options](https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/) in 2.0.